# Redirecting a user from one view to another or with within a SignalR Hub

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, view, signalr-hub

I have MVC application which uses signalR . Currently I have only 1 form (cshtml) which has login and other details. When I click on login connection to hub starts

```
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('#login').click(function () {
        // call the Login method on the hub
        var tokenRequestResponse = integrationServerHub.server
            .login($('#username').val(), $('#password').val())
            .done(processTokenRequestResponse);
        $('#events').val('');
        $('#events').prepend("login.click" + "\n");
    });
```

And when Login is successful I hide login div panel & display other contents of page so that my hub connection continue receive events. 
I want to move login form to another view and when login is successful it should redirect to another view  and my hub connection should start to receive events to new view. How can I achieve this.

Comment: I could see that you're binding the login event once the hub has started. Is the hub currently working? If that's working, why not work on the `listening` part?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: hub is working and application receives events. I am thinking of starting hub after login event when redirected to 2nd view.

Answer (score 0):

I did same after login success use

```
enter code here->return (RedirectToAction("chatIndex", "Home", new { Username = loggedInUser.USERID }));
```

where chatIndex is my Chat window with list of all online offline users.